# What options except cutting the tree down do I have if a fir tree is growing too high?

Tags: trees

There's a fir tree that is now about seven meter tall and continues to grow and will reach something like 20 meters height. The tree is too close to buildings and too close to plants and so the shadow it casts is a problem and also the perspective of it growing to 20 meters is also a problem.

Cutting the tree down at earth level is an options but it doesn't feel good - it would be nice to have some medium size or small tree there.

Maybe I can cut it at three-four meters height? What other options are there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coniferous evergreens do not respond well to pruning to keep them smaller.  Unlike a deciduous tree when they are cut back they do not grow more at the side. If you "top" the tree a new leader will [start from the top](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apical_dominance) but this will not have as good an attachment and becomes a point of weakness or even potential hazard in the future. [This document](http://www.cals.uidaho.edu/edcomm/pdf/bul/bul0644.pdf) is worth reading, if only for the amusing 1950's era drawings of a puzzled homeowner.

If you had an interest in getting on a tall ladder every year you could keep the tree smaller by trimming the leader.

Practically, if the tree is in the wrong place now it will only get worse. Consult a local arborist and consider removing it now while it is not that big a job. Whatever the price is now, both the tree and the bill will only increase through the years.